# SAP Catching Data with RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION RFC VB

Tags: vb.net, saprfc

I become an errorcode 1001, an SAP Remote error?

I've googled alot but didn't find anything.
Maybe someone knows whats the Problem here.
Im using SAP 720.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x000003E9): SAP Remote
>   Function Call    bei
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o,
>   Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames,
>   Boolean[] CopyBack)    bei
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) ...

Here is my code:

```
    Public FunctionCtrl As Object
    Function login_Call()
    Try

        Dim conn As Object
        FunctionCtrl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
        conn = FunctionCtrl.Connection


        conn.System = XXX
        conn.ApplicationServer = XXX
        conn.SystemNumber = XXX
        conn.Client = "XXX"
        conn.user = XXX
        conn.Password = XXX
        conn.Language = XXX
        'needed for frontend dialog
        conn.RfcWithDialog = True

        'log on with logon dialog
        If Not conn.Logon(0, 1) Then
            Dim WsShell
            Dim intText As Integer
            WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            intText = WsShell.Popup("Logon not succesful." & vbCrLf & _
                               "will be closed automatically in one minute...", 60)
            'conn = Nothing
            Anmeldung_Call = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        Anmeldung_Call = True

    Catch ex As Exception

        Anmeldung_Call = False
    End Try
    Me.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function

Sub Open_IW73()
    Dim BdcTable As Object
    Dim RfcCallTransaction As Object
    Dim Messages As Object
    Dim count As Integer

    'call transaction IW73
    RfcCallTransaction = FunctionCtrl.Add("RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION")
    RfcCallTransaction.Exports("TRANCODE") = "IW73"
    RfcCallTransaction.Exports("UPDMODE") = "S"
    BdcTable = RfcCallTransaction.Tables("BDCTABLE").....
```

**The Error comes in this line: "RfcCallTransaction = FunctionCtrl.Add("RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION")
"**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error. People suggested different fixes like using SAP.functions.Unicode.
What did it for me was simply changing to "RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION_USING". I'm not sure of the exact difference between these commands, so be careful with that. So far it has been working for me though.